How to load balance IHttpClientFactory in .NET Core?
I am consuming two endpoints that returns same responses. I want to consume them by order like load balancer logic. First request send to service1 and other service2.
I have defined the services like this:
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("service1", config =>
{
    var url = "https://service1.com/api";
    config.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
});

builder.Services.AddHttpClient("service2", config =>
{
    var url = "https://service2.com/api";
    config.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
});

But how to load balance them while calling?

What do you imply with load balance? Do you have something like client site round robin in mind to randomly use service1 or 2? Or actual Load Balancing by a middle man that knows about the actual load of the backing system and can route accordingly?

Round robin is good solution.

Then inject IHttpClientFactory into the service that needs a HttpClient, in that class use the Random class to create the service1,service2 string randomly and ask the factory for a client by that name (via the IHttpClientFactory.CreateClient method).
